# Meteor with connection mongolab server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mlab, database

Connection string :

```
To connect using the shell:
mongo ds031183.mongolab.com:31183/mara -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
To connect using a driver via the standard URI (what's this?):
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds031183.mongolab.com:31183/mara
```

How to connection remote database in meteor  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the MONGO_URL environment variable when starting up meteor

`$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds031183.mongolab.com:31183/mara meteor`

Comment: Where exactly do you put this?

Comment: Yes, same : Where exactly do you put this?

Comment: where is to above two comments answers?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry that I didn't answer. I've updated my answer, just put it in front of `meteor` command